# 'Scheduled in several months', is it ok?

Tags: prepositions

If something is scheduled for, say, December, and you're speaking in March, how do you phrase it? 'Scheduled in several months', is it ok?

Comment: Strictly speaking it should be *Scheduled **for** several months **from now***. Feasibly you could use ***in*** with *Scheduled **in** December*, but strictly speaking that preposition should be preceded by something like *scheduled **to take place** in December* (and *It's scheduled **for** December* would be far more common). Having said all that, any native speaker would understand your version, and a few might even use it themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's okay, but a bit pointless.  It doesn't really tell me if it is in June or December.

If you know it is December then

> You next appointment has been scheduled in (or for) December.

or perhaps "next winter" if you can't be so precise.

If you just want to say that it *won't* be soon, then a negative expression is called for.

> Your next appointment won't be scheduled for several months

You can soften the blow a bit with:

> I'm afraid, due to the COVID lockdown, it won't be possible to schedule your next appointment for several months.

And even then, in March, I'd be expecting it in perhaps August or September.

Comment: FumbleFingers says it should be 'for several months from now'. Is it true?